# How to update MFC source code?

Tags: c++, mfc

After several Visual Studio patches and a service pack or two, my MFC source code no longer matches my MFC binaries. When I trace into MFC, I either see assembly or old source code.

How do I get my MFC sources to match my binaries again?

Comment: No, the problem is that a service pack has updated my binaries but not my source code. I can't find the current MFC source code. Rebuilding would put me back to where I was prior to the updates.

Comment: What is the version number of your binaries?  9.0.30729.4148 should be current.

Comment: This is a VS2005 project and the MFC dll is version 8.0.50727.4053.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no other answers I'll tell you the obvious (and the most painful) one. Reinstall everything. And if possible install Visual Studio with SP slipstreamed.

Although I don't know what you meant by "old source", I don't think there were any changes to MFC between Visual Studio 2005 and SP1. But I might be mistaking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not picking it up automatically - when you build a dll, the source location is stamped in the pdb. Anyway, try setting the source file path in Visual Studio to first point to the "updated" MFC source. If that doesn't work, step into the MFC function again (so you get the "incorrect" source), then close out that file, then browse to and open the "correct" source file. See if the debugger jumps to the appropriate location then.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the updated MFC source code. Where can I get that? Some VS service pack updated all the binaries on my machine, but never updated the source code. 


What can (or should) update the MFC source code? It didn't happen on my machine, so I'll do it manually. Any idea where I can download the MFC sources?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of updates from the MS download centre, [searching MFC.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?pocId=&freetext=mfc&DisplayLang=en) but the only one mentioning source is the [OLEUI2.cpp update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933273) to VS.Net 2003. Maybe it hasn't actually been changed but does need recompiling?